# why does pkill autocomplete on alt+f1 terminal, but not on a regular X terminal?

Tags: command-line

I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and logged in, and realized if I type `pkill l` and then tab twice, it will show me all the processes starting with `l`.  So I went to `gnome-terminal` in X, and tried it, but I got  nothing [besides filenames].

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: It works here...

Comment: Is the output of `complete -p | grep kill` the same in both terminals?

Comment: Alt-F1 gives you a login shell. When bash is invoked as a login shell, it reads different configuration files (see `man bash`). Since pkill autocomplete works for me and enzotib in gnome-terminal, too, can you please check, whether you have modified some of the shell configuration files?

Comment: @arrange, `complete -p` output is blank on gnome-terminal. I would try it on Alt+F1, except it isn't loading the Alt+number terminals right now [Need to reboot]..  So I tried `sudo login` in gnome-terminal, and tried logging in as my user, and then I tried pkill and tab, and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that in the `~/.bashrc` file (or `/etc/bash.bashrc`) there are lines (towards the end)

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: appended that to ~/.bashrc and it works